# multiply 2 columns until get a desired value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, while-loop

Greeting everyone,

I have this table (Without the Res_Problem):

| ID | Problem | X | Impact | Prob | Res_Problem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 12 | IDC1 | 1 | 2 | (12-2)=10 |
| ID1 | 12 | IDC2 | 2 | 2 | (10-4)=6 STOP |
| ID1 | 12 | IDC3 | 1 | 0 | NO LOOP |
| ID1 | 12 | IDC4 | 1 | 0 | NO LOOP |
| ID2 | 10 | IDB1 | 1 | 2 | New Loop (10-2)=8 |
| ID2 | 10 | IDB1 | 1 | 2 | (8-2) = 6 STOP |

I want to do a loop that multiplies the Impact and prob until get a desire value (6 for example),and stop the loop until it reach the 6. but start again the loop on the ID2... and so on, any suggestions?

I think it has to be something like this :

while (df['Problem'] - df['Impact']*df['Impact'] < 6):
df['loop'] = res

The loop should create the 'Res_Problem' column

Comment: It is not clear how how want the result displayed. Is the column `Res_Problem` what you want result to displayed? Is the `Res_Problem` just a example of the logic the loop solution should do or just part of the original data?

Comment: Can you just show what the final result should look like?

Comment: @ShaneS Hello! The Res Problem is the new column i want, result of the loop

Comment: okay, So you want the column to contain a string of values...

Comment: @ShaneS I want the new column show the current value unitl it reachs the desire value (6), the string are a example for the "non importants" next rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
s = (df['Problem']
 .sub(df['Impact'].mul(df['Prob'])
      .groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()
      )
)

m = s.le(6).groupby(df['ID']).shift(fill_value=False)

df['Res_Problem'] = s.mask(m)
```

output:

```
    ID  Problem     X  Impact  Prob  Res_Problem
0  ID1       12  IDC1       1     2         10.0
1  ID1       12  IDC2       2     2          6.0
2  ID1       12  IDC3       1     0          NaN
3  ID1       12  IDC4       1     0          NaN
4  ID2       10  IDB1       1     2          8.0
5  ID2       10  IDB1       1     2          6.0
```